# With respects to the North Channel (Irish Channel), has a causeway ever been proposed for a crossing?

Tags: structural-engineering, structures, marine-engineering

Former UK Prime Minister, Boris Johnson raised the issue of a bridge between Scotland and Northern Ireland; his impromptu estimate of £15 billion was probably a little wide of the mark.

The issues are a sea crossing of 12 miles (19 km) with a deep sea trench (Beaufort's Dyke) some 2 miles (3.22 km) wide and a 1000 feet (305 m) deep.  There is a large quantity of old munitions (perhaps a million tons) dumped in the trench; and possibly some nuclear waste.

Johnson commissioned a review in 2020 of the UK's transportation system covering road, rail, air and fixed infrastructure. The review was largely conducted by apparatchiks of London Transport and, surprisingly, focused on rail issues. However two eminent civil engineers (mostly experienced in rail projects) looked at the proposed bridge crossing and thought that it might be technically feasible but would take 30 years and cost £335 billion!

Even given the colossal over-runs that accompany any government sponsored project in the UK I thought this rather over-egged the pudding.
However, I understand that there is a surprisingly strong current running through the North Channel and this prompted the thought that a causeway with integrated power generation might be feasible. The power output would be enormous.

Has any engineer (obviously with wider experience than just of rail technology) ever looked at this and proposed a causeway?

Addition:  It seems not; which is a little surprising. A back of the envelope calculation suggests a cost of about 15 to 20 billions. Not including connecting roads or the cost of power generating equipment.
The average flow rate through the North Channel is about .15m/s. Does anyone have any idea what the prospective power generation might be?

Comment: Only after 4 Guinness

Comment: One minor problem, British railways use a track gauge of 1,435 mm. Ireland uses 1,600 mm. There are about 6 million people living on the island of Ireland. £335 billion would be about £56k per head (although we wouldn't be paying).

Comment: @Transistor:  Two ways around such a problem would be having a dual gauge rail line, or a bogey exchange system, where prior to traveling on the link or arrival from the link, all the bogeys on the train would be swapped over for bogeys with the appropriate gauge wheels for the next leg of the journey. The first is expensive & the second operationally tedious, time consuming & inefficient.

Comment: Four [British Isle sea links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_British_Isles_fixed_sea_link_connections) have been suggested over time. The Kintyre & Galloway routes would have linked Scotland & Northern Ireland & the Tuskar & Irish Mail routes would have linked Wales with the Republic of Ireland.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Useful to know that only one proposal for a causeway was made and that in Victorian times. Even that was part of a general suggestion of a crossing with absolutely no details. Naturally, a causeway would be used for road and rail transport in addition to electricity production.

Comment: Oh! and by the way Inspiration only comes after 5 Guinnesses!

Comment: Regarding tidal energy numbers, have a look at David McKay's book, Sustainable Energy Without the Hot Air which is available free online at http://withouthotair.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, However, not really appropriate. The North channel has a complex flow. Nett northerly but complicated by southern ebb flow. I don't think that anyone has looked at, what is effectively, a 12 mile barrage but with no lagoon. Water speeds peak at 3 m/s. Possibility of wave harvesting the full length and, perhaps, wind turbines the full length.. Back of an envelope and I got 4GW; but this must be over-egging it!